# Pass special characters as string between Windows Phone 8 pages

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, special-characters

I am trying to pass a special character as string such as `&` or `#` entered by user in the text box.

Then pass this string to the next page

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(String.Format("/Pages/EditNote.xaml?note={0}", strText), UriKind.Relative));
```

The `EditNote.xaml` page then checks for the note parameter and get its value

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        if (NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("note"))
        {
            noteText = NavigationContext.QueryString["note"];
        }
}
```

The problem is noteText will always be empty when it's a non alphanumeric characters such as `&`, `#` etc.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Since special characters have predefined meaning in url construction, it will get confuse with url + data with special characters.

You can use IsolatedStorageSettings also if its ok in your context.

Source page:

```
IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

if (!settings.Contains("note"))
{
     settings.Add("note", "$#$#$#%#%#????===&&&&&some note Text!#@#@@@  someText @$$@%@%@%@^@@&^*@&(*(**)*)_((_(_(_*(&*(^*&%&%*)");
}

settings.Save();

NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(@"/Pages/EditNote.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

Destination page:

```
string note = string.Empty;
IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
if (settings.Contains("note"))
{
    note = settings["note"] as string;
}
```

here you can pass all special characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use UrlEncoding to get the special characters encoded.